# Doxygen - How to generate a textual call relationship result without generating the graph

Tags: c++, c, doxygen

I am using Doxygen to get the whole function call graph for the c/c++ project. I set `HAVE_DOT = YES` and `CALL_GRAPH = YES`. It can help get the right results but for a big project, it will cost much time to generate the PNG using dot. I want to get a textual result without PNG to avoid time consuming. But I do not know how to config. It will be perfect to get `.DOT` files without generating PNG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the graphical representation doxygen has the `CALL_GRAPH`, `CALLER_GRAPH` together with the `HAVE_DOT` configuration settings.

For a textual representation there are the settings: `REFERENCED_BY_RELATION` and `REFERENCES_RELATION`, these setting result in a per function result.

From the comment by the OP:

> But it just helps me to know what entities are called in a function. I
>   can not get the whole call graph for the project.

and

> What I want is to get the functions call graph in textual graph like .DOT without generating PNG.

this is not directly supported by doxygen. There is a mean trick to accomplish something:

- set `HAVE_DOT` to `YES`
- set `CALL_GRAPH` to `NO`
- add to the function of which you want the relations: `\callgraph`
- the mean trick:

  - set `DOT_CLEANUP` to `NO`
  - set `DOT_PATH` to a path where the `dot` executable does not reside
  - set `DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES` to an appropriate value
  - set `MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH` to an appropriate value

this will result in a `dot` file (in e.g. the html directory) with the relations as requested.

Comment: I have tried setting `REFERENCES_RELATION = YES`.  But it just helps me to know what entities are called in a function. I can not get the whole call graph for the project.

Comment: The `REFER...` do it indeed just on function base (so the direct  called / called by relation, 1 deep). This extra 'whole graph' part was not clear from the question, please add this information to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the manual below: 
http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/diagrams.html

Setting `CALL_GRAPH = NO` may work as it will not create the graphical representation.

Have a look at the usage of `\hidecallgraph` and `\callgraph` in the manual.

Comment: According to my interpretation OP wants " I want to get a textual result" not just suppress the graph, though for disabling individual graphs `\hidecall...`  can be used.

Comment: My complete interpretation is that OP wants "to get a textual result without PNG" as it is time-consuming to generate PNG and requirement is to avoid it. So disabling it can be an option. Although @albert answer also points towards textual representation.

Comment: When disabling the `CALL_GRAPH` there is no textual representation, the normal textual representation of the graph is in a `.dot` file and this file is not generated  in this case. The `REFER...` settings generate a textual representation in the `HTML, `LaTeX`, ... output.

Comment: What I want is to get the functions call graph in textual graph like `.DOT` without generating PNG.